# Powershell: Tail last line and remove it

Tags: powershell

How can I use powershell -tail param to remove the last line from a file?

The following line gets the last line, but , when I set the content to the file it just stores that last line and disregards the rest...

```
Get-content $file -tail 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can't

`Get-Content -Tail $N` only *reads* the last `$N` lines, it doesn't *remove* anything.

Most efficient way is probably using the [`System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3k7ax020(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`WriteAllBytes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.100).aspx) methods:

```
# Read all lines
$LinesInFile = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($file)
# Write all lines, except for the last one, back to the file
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file,$LinesInFile[0..($LinesInFile.Count - 2)])
# Clean up
Remove-Variable -Name LinesInFile
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, with you code, how can I read the encoding type of the file as ANSI and write it as ANSI, problem is with a particular file that has a (£) pound sign, the encoding type for this particular file is getting changed to UTF-8 and is making this pound sign unreadable. thanks